# Issues with "Generating New Processes" when called by different applications?

Tags: android, linux, facebook, process, fork

We understand that being with linux kernel, android generates new process and assigns new process ID or each application when launched. My concern is about what happens when the same application (or its activity) is called from different parent processes? and both running at the time. For example user clicked on "login with facebook" for application A and facebook's login activity is started. Now without completing this login, user brings Application B on foreground and clicks "login with facebook" button on this application. Now two facebook processes are running at the same time. Does the android creates two processes for each child facebook process or handle both with single process ?

**UPDATE**

I have changed the question scenario little bit. To make it more clear. 
My mobile has candy crush saga, subway surfer and facebook apps installed. Now,

First task stack is as : candy crush->login with facebook-> facebook login

Second task stack is as : subway surfer->login with facebook -> facebook login

Here both facebook login screens are active (not dead). Bur when checked with runningProcess, It seems both screens are dealt with single processID. My concern is how does the android manage two instances of the same applications being handled by single process at the same time ??

Comment: "Now two facebook processes are running at the same time" -- and your proof of this is, what, exactly?

Comment: @CommonsWare, Centre of my question relies in this sentence. using "two facebook activities are running....." might have been better. But my point is, facebook is the topactivity for both task stack or it is still running on both application A and B.

Comment: You talk about Facebook, first of all Facebook sdk has its own FacebookActivity that handles login thing, if you have two applications, and those applications need Facebook Login, then these two will call separate FacebookActivity in their Activity Stack. If you are talking about Facebook App installed, then two application start LoginActivity of the app with different intents, then for every call there will be two separate LoginAcvtivities in Facebook App's Activity Stack. I hope you understand.

Answer (score 0):

> Bur when checked with runningProcess, It seems both screens are dealt with single processID

Correct.

> how does the android manage two instances of the same applications being handled by single process at the same time ?

There is only one instance of the application. There may be two instances of the login activity.